# Extract a piece of string before the first occurance of an integer

Tags: php, regex

I was working on a Php script. But unfortunately I am really poor at REGEX part. I want to extract something like this.

The String I am give is:

> Hello World! 2016 Have a nice day ahead!

Now, I want to split it Into an Array as

> {"1":"Hello World!","2":"Have a nice day ahead!"}

I want to separate it when it encounters an Integer. Its Just, I need a Regular Expression For this. Can someone please Help me out with this? Also, please suggest me some links which can help me learn REGEX. Thank You so much in advance.

Comment: 1. Why must it be a regex? 2. What are you splitting on, the fixed string  " 2016 "?

Comment: the string 2016 is not fixed. It can be any integer.

Comment: Please add the full specification - the basis for the split - to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`preg_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). It is obvious what it does (splits a string by a regex pattern), and it produces output that closely matches your requirements:

```
php > $s = "Hello World! 2016 Have a nice day ahead!";
php > $pattern = "/\s+\d+\s+/";
php > $a = preg_split($pattern, $s);
php > print_r($a);
Array
(
    [0] => Hello World!
    [1] => Have a nice day ahead!
)
```

The only difference is that your question requests 1-based indexing whereas this answer provides 0-based indexing. You should prefer 0-based indexing because that is the default for PHP sequences i.e. arrays, strings, etc.

Providing links to resources is beyond the scope of SO, however, you could try:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html
- http://regexone.com/
- http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm

or any of the hundreds of thousands of others reachable from a simple google search.

---

Alternatively, if you know the literal value of the delimiting string, you can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
php > $s = "Hello World! 2016 Have a nice day ahead!";
php > $delimiter = " 2016 ";
php > $a = explode($delimiter, $s);
php > print_r($a);
Array
(
    [0] => Hello World!
    [1] => Have a nice day ahead!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`/^([\D]+)\s+\d+\s+(.*)$/` should do it.

You get all non-digits, then digits with white-space around them, then the rest.

Putting it all together:

```
$string = 'Hello World! 2016 Have a nice day ahead!';
preg_match('/^([\D]+)\s+\d+\s+(.*)$/', $string, $match);
// $match[1]: Hello World!
// $match[2]: Have a nice day ahead!
```

Comment: Thank You So Much! That made some sense. Bt I wont mark your answer correct till both my questions are answered.

Comment: @Milind use http://regexone.com/ and http://regexr.com/ to learn regular expressions.

Comment: I like the cheat sheet here: http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/, and quick testing at https://regex101.com/